# Upload image to server with XMLHttpRequest and FormData in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to upload image to server with progress by using the example provided by:

`https://gist.github.com/Tamal/9231005f0c62e1a3f23f60dc2f46ae35`

I checked some tutorials, the code should works. But the uri in Android show uri

`uri: content://media/external/images/media/4985`

The URI come from the component

`https://github.com/jeanpan/react-native-camera-roll-picker`

The URI should be

`file://....`

So, why the upload code not working.

How can I convert the

`content://...` to `file://....` to make it possible to upload image to server in React-native? or does my assumed is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I am using **react-native-image-picker** to get image from library. I have written following code in one method name as **selectPhoto()** to select image from library.

```
selectedPhoto = () => {
//Open Image Picker

const options = {
  quality: 1.0,
  maxWidth: 500,
  maxHeight: 500,
};

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  //console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    let source = {uri :response.uri};
    console.log(source.uri);
    this.setState({
      profilePhoto: source
    });
  }
}); }
```

This will give me uri of selected image and I have set in state variable. then write following code to upload image.

```
var profiePicture = {
    uri: this.state.profilePhoto.uri,
    type: 'image/jpg', // or photo.type image/jpg
    name: 'testPhotoName',
  }

  // API to upload image
  fetch('http://www.example.com/api/uploadProfilePic/12345', {
    method: 'post',
    headers:{
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'profile_pic' : profiePicture
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

This code is working in one of the my project.

Comment: I think even I use your mentioned component, it provided as uri: 'content://media/external/images/media/4985' as what I use.

Comment: I'm learning react native and today I had preparing demo to upload image. This is working fine for me.